# Hawkes process as OU with jumps?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I believe the Hawkes process conditional intensity $\lambda_t$ can be interpreted as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck type process, but with jumps instead of the usual Brownian motion.  Is this a correct interpretation?  I cannot find this connection made explicit in the Hawkes literature.

For a very verbose derivation: Given the OU SDE
$$
d\lambda_t = -\beta(\lambda_t - \mu) \ dt + \alpha \ dN_t
$$
where $N_t$ is a jump process with unit jumps, multiply through by $e^{\beta t}$, apply Ito's lemma, and integrate
$$
\begin{align*}
e^{\beta t} \ d\lambda_t + \beta(\lambda_t - \mu) e^{\beta t} \ dt &= \alpha e^{\beta t} \ dN_t \\
\int_0^t d[e^{\beta t}(\lambda_t - \mu)] &= \int_0^t \alpha e^{\beta s} \ dN_s \\
\lambda_t &= e^{-\beta t}\lambda_0 + \mu + \int_0^t \alpha e^{-\beta (t-s)} \ dN_s
\end{align*}
$$
The integral can be rewritten as an explicit sum over the jumps, which are known,
$$
\lambda_t = e^{-\beta t}\lambda_0 + \mu + \sum_{i: \ t_i < t} \alpha e^{-\beta(t-t_i)}
$$
and assuming no initial impulse, $\lambda_0 = 0$, we recover the typical statement of a univariate Hawkes intensity.